# Are there any big performance boost when upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, performance, performance-tuning, database-performance

If I run the server as MySQL database. (Assume using the same MySQL version).

Are there any big performance boost when upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 22.04?

Comment: I find the security boost more relevant.

Comment: No performance boost.  For help with slow queries, ask stackoverflow.com

Comment: As above, 16.04 is no longer supported/actively maintained. So that's a good reason to upgrade on its own.